Microsoft C++ exception std::bad_array_new_length at memory address <..>
I'm writing some code in C++ using VS2022. And it throws out the error above.
Here's the code:
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    int arr[1000];
    int i = 0;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin >> arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int n = 0; n < i + 1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[n] > max)
            max = arr[n];
    }
    int* arr2 = new int[i+1];
    for (int n = 0; n < i + 1; n++)
    {
        arr2[n] = max - arr[n];
        fout << arr2[n];
    }
    delete[] arr2;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}

The program is supposed to find the maximum value (max) in an array (arr) created from an input file (input.txt). It then creates another array (arr2) and fills it with max - arr[n]. IT then outputs arr2 to an output file (output.txt)
Maybe it'll sound unrestrained, but what the hell is going on? Any ideas?

Side note, in current C++ you should not usually not  have to use new/delete. Use std::vector instead. Also read your file into a std::vector<int>. std::vector<int> valurs; int value; while(fin >> value) values.push_back(value); And then you can use std::max_element to get your maximum.

This isn't the problem, but while (!fin.eof()) won't do wha you're looking for. eof() is true after an attempted input has failed; it tells you why the input failed. So that loop will store one extra value in the array. Use while (fin >> arr[i]) instead.

Also, you don't have to call fin.close() and fout.close(). The destructors will do that.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

Don't update the question when you get an answer. Ask a new question.

@PeteBecker hey, might sound stupid, but what is a destructor? i've been taught that not doing fin.close() and fout.close() causes memory leaks, but destructors were never mentioned.

@BeamWasHere -- every class has a constructor (often more than one) that's used to initialize an object of that type when it's created, and every class has a destructor that cleans up the object when it goes away.

Your first for loop is messed up:
for (int n = 0; n < i + 1; i++)

since i is your array size (contrary to usual naming conventions, if I may add that), and you keep increasing that instead of n (which is your looping variable), the only way for that loop to exit is when i overflows so it turns negative. Which is likely messing up the allocation that follows -- a large negative size is certainly a "bad length".

Fun fact: for anyone with some experience, this could be a textbook example of why it's a bad idea to use a variable named i for something like that :-) The world is full of loops like for (int i=0; i<something; i++), so it's almost like muscle-memory to write the i++...
... although in modern times, this has diminished a bit since we have range-based for loops or iterators. But, I'm still doing plenty of the classic counting loops.

When i overflows, the behaviour is undefined.       While the result with some implementations is turning negative, that is neither required nor guaranteed - and implementations where it does not occur do exist.

In addition, the i + 1 is wrong, should just be i.

oh, really, im stupid. thanks!

@Peter yes, but I needed a flow of events that would explain a "bad length" exception from this bug, and a given compiler not bothering about overflows seemed like an easy assumption to make. This is more of a blind post-mortem analysis, not a claim that integer overflows always turn negative.
